# Queenstown, New Zealand private transfers

Tags: transportation, new-zealand, queenstown

Are there private transfer companies to take me from Queenstown, New Zealand to Te Anau, New Zealand?

Comment: It's a ~2 hour drive, so any taxi driver is likely to be happy to take your money for the trip! Or are you after a shared transfer?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by private transfer.  You're unlikely to find a dedicated pick-up/drop-off service because, as mentioned, it's a two hour drive.  However there are companies that offer daily bus links between the two, e.g. [TrackNet](http://www.tracknet.net/tracknet/queenstown-transport-134).

Comment: I traveled with TrackNet from Queenstown to Te Anau in late Jan 2014. Key point was that they had two departures daily - one around 7AM and one around 4:30PM. The pickup was Queenstown central business district and the bus stops at the airport bus stop to pickup travellers at the airport before continuing to Te Anau.